# X3D Relative URL's

Tags: netbeans, vrml, x3d

So I'm developing an X3D scene with NetBeans and the X3D plugins (Similar to X3D-Edit), after validating my file with the built in quality assurance validator I get the following error;

```
<Inline DEF='MyModel'/> url array address(es) missing 
online http/https references (url='"model.x3d"') 
[/X3D/Scene/Group/Transform[1]/Inline, info]
```

It seems to want an online URL to refer to the inline node. My question is, can I somehow use a relative URL instead of an online one? I have tried using the `file://` protocol but i get
another error when doing so;

```
<Inline DEF='MyModel'/> url array contains file:/ local address, 
not portable across Web servers (url='"file://model.x3d"') [/X3D/Scene/Group/Transform[2]/Inline, warning]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cand find this in the VRML node reference:

"The Inline node is a grouping node that reads its children data from a location in the World Wide Web"

http://www.web3d.org/x3d/specifications/vrml/ISO-IEC-14772-VRML97/part1/nodesRef.html#Inline

which means the inline url cannot point to a local file

You can also read this:
http://www.web3d.org/x3d/specifications/vrml/ISO-IEC-14772-VRML97/part1/concepts.html#4.5

Comment: That must be it then. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question was provided in the first response of the X3D Validator.  Composed:

```
<Inline DEF='MyModel' url='"model.x3d"'/>
```

Note that the "quoted address" is necessary since X3D url attributes contain an array of strings, known as type MFString.  This approach allows inclusion of additional backup addresses (such as an online address) for maximum reliability.  Each individual address is expected to be an equivalent version of the same X3D model.  This array is an ordered list: the first successfully loaded model is used.

More on relative url addresses, Inline nodes and validation can be found at

- X3D Scene Authoring Hints: URL Links http://www.web3d.org/x3d/content/examples/X3dSceneAuthoringHints.html#urls
- X3D Tooltips, Inline: http://www.web3d.org/x3d/content/X3dTooltips.html#Inline
- X3D Validator: https://savage.nps.edu/X3dValidator